# Adding points along line at varying distances in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, arcgis-10.5, lines-to-points

I have a shapefile for a single (3 km) line generated from a start and end location of a trail. I would like to create a new shapefile with points along the line that are not of an equal distances apart. I have all the point labels with the distances in an Excel speadsheet.

I am familiar with "Contruct Points" in the ArcMap editor, but this does not allow for varying distances. For example, I would like the first point at the beginning of the line, the next 47 meters from the starting point of the line, the next point 46 meters from the next point point, the next 48 meters, etc.

How can I do this in ArcMap 10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Points Along Line Tool in 10.5.  You could generate individual points and merge the results together.  Or you could generate points at every interval and select out the ones you want with a query.  Either option would be an easy Modelbuilder exercise.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-points-along-lines.htm

The is a also a Python solution (position along line) if you have those skills.
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm

Comment: I have never used Modelbuilder or Python. In the former case, looking at the link you addressed, I do not see that the "Point_Placement" parameter which calls the optional "distance" parameter would allow for a string with 80 different distance values needed along my line. Is that correct? It seems this feature only allows for a single distance parameter.

Comment: Right, so use Points along the line to generate the points at every meter, use your string of distances in a query on the output points, export the selection to a new featureclass.